# What was supposed to appear in EGA after Chapter IV?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ho.history-overview

We find a nice table on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89l%C3%A9ments_de_g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie_alg%C3%A9brique) mentioning for instance that abelian schemes were supposed to be discussed in Chapter XII.

Did anyone involved in EGA say anything more detailed, verbally or in written form, about what was supposed to appear in EGA?

Comment: Grothendieck gave his prenotes for EGA V to Piotr Blass, and they can be found on the web https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/unpubtexts.php

Comment: The table you cite gives very accurate sources for the additional content in EGA that is treated in the various SGA plus FGA and Hearthstone's seminar on duality.